# Android https handshake terminated exception

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, handshake

I'm getting this exception randomly when trying to make https request, sometimes it works and sometimes failed to make handshaking with this exception.
And I'm trying with lollipop and marshmallow.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: 
SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x9d397c00: Failure in SSL library,  usually a protocol error
error:100c543e:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0x9b0bb3e0:0x00000001)
```

Here's how I'm making the requests

```
URL url;
HttpURLConnection connection;
try {
    String serverUrl = "...";
    url = new URL(serverUrl);

    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        Log.i(TAG, "OK");
        Log.i(TAG, "response " + in.readLine());
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error " + responseCode);
    }

    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```